# SQL Server 2008 Database rights

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

In one of the SSIS package there are 5 data flow tasks where in it is pulling data from 5 tables from Source DB and dumping as it is in destination database. However when I connect to source DB using SQL Server Management studio with same user as that used in SSIS connection manager for Source DB, it does not show any table. It  does not even allow to select specific columns data from those table, only allows to do "select *" from those table. Please let me know what type of permissions are given to this user ?

Comment: I need more information.  Is the source DB located in an instance on a separate server (computer other than where you're developing SSIS)?  Are you using a Windows account or SQL Server authorization?  Are you trying to connect to the DB through Object Explorer of SQL Server Management Studio on your own computer or are you remoting to the server where the instance is set up that is hosting the DB you're trying to access?  At this point, it sounds as though part of the issue is that the user permissions are limited to a public server role with perhaps db_datareader database role.

Comment: Source DB is located on different server. SQL Authentication is used to access source DB. I am trying to access the source DB  through SQL Server Mgmt Studio on my own computer. I do not have access on the source DB server to access it remotely.

Comment: Have you checked with the DBA or person who has sysadmin access to the SQL Server instance hosting the database on the remote server?  It sounds like somebody has set up column-level permissions on the tables you query and added you to a group to which that applies.  For this, you will need the help of somebody who can access the database with sysadmin server role.  If column-level (or schema-level) permissions is the issue, then it makes little sense that they would be applied to an ETL developer who needs to see the columns consistently between SSIS and SSMS.